# Django and google_streetview API

Tags: django, api

Is there a way to retrieve a street view image from google_streetview API in Python/Django and pass it to templates without having to save the image within Django?

I know you can create an API call using Javascript, although I am looking to see if there is a method to do the API call in the backend to avoid showing my API Key in the frontend or is this even necessary? I am not even sure what might be best practice for this. I am currently using Javascript to allow for the Google Places Autocomplete API. Is it secure enough to simply have restrictions in place on your API key's for which API your key is good for and a Application Restriction?

Currently I have this in place from the google_streetview package:

```
import google_streetview.api

def streetview(coord):
params = [{
    'size': '300x200', 
    'location': coord,
    'fov': '100',
    'key': settings.STREETVIEW_KEY
}]
results = google_streetview.api.results(params)
```

However, the only things I know you can do with results is .preview(), .save_links(), .download_links(), .save_metadata().

Comment: What about [django-google-maps](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-maps/) ?

Comment: I believe that just works with just the Google Places API and not the Street View Static API that I am making a request to